# What is the data type of pair's element in vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, char, std-pair

I need to temporary declare firstElement from pair which is in vector

```
vector<pair<char*, int> > rezVector; //is  vector I'm using
auto tempPair = rezVector[0].first; //Is solution I got, but my teacher won't accept (I must know data type)
```

I've already tried

```
char tempPair;
char* tempPair;
char tempPair[20];
```

**EDIT**
For those, who want to know how I use it:

```
 sort(rezVector.begin(), rezVector.end(), compareFn);
char*& tempPair = rezVector[0].first; //Already with solution
for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<m-1; j++){
        if(rezVector[i].second == rezVector[j].second){
            if(strcmp(rezVector[i].first, rezVector[j].first)>0){
                tempPair = rezVector[i].first;
                rezVector[i].first = rezVector[j].first;
                rezVector[j].first = tempPair;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you used them and how they didn't work?  `char* tempPair` should have been correct.

Comment: Technically you get a `char*&`...

Comment: char* should be fine. What do you have as error ?

Comment: Do you mean `vector<pair<char*, int> >::value_type::first_type` ?

Comment: @Slava I love it.  It's a mouthful but it is "the data type" :)

Comment: i would tell the teacher that the type is `decltype( rezVector[0].first)`, though for me it was always more important to make fun of teachers rather than making them happy

Comment: `char*&` works!

Comment: @Slava or even `std::add_reference_t<std::remove_reference_t<std::vector<std::pair<char *, int>>::reference>::first_type>`

Comment: Note that context you posted probably doesn't do what you want it to, particularly when the first element of the vector is sorted correctly

Comment: I checked and it does it's duty, it is sorting vector by second element and for those values which are equal - sorting them by key

Comment: If it swaps any entries, it will overwrite the value in `rezVector[0].first`

Comment: @LizardDerad If you want to find out the type of anything else again, use this snippet: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/B0kw9r . Look inside the `type_revealer` for the type

Comment: Depending on what `compareFn` does, it might be that everything after the first line does nothing

Comment: It seems strange that your teacher told you to use `char*&`, instead of telling you to remove everything apart from `sort(rezVector.begin(), rezVector.end(), compareFn);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher could plausibly be expecting a wide variety of things, including

```
char * temp = rezVector[0].first;
char *& temp = rezVector[0].first;
const char * temp = rezVector[0].first;
std::string temp = rezVector[0].first;
std::string_view temp = rezVector[0].first;
```

You will have to ask them the intended purpose of `temp` to know which (if any) is the answer they are looking for.

Comment: you're correct, `char *& temp = rezVector[0].first;` is what I'm looking for`

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a pair's `.first` actually gives you a reference to the respective entry, such that `rezVector[0].first` will have type `char*&`. This allows you to alter the contents of  `rezVector[0].first`, if you actually want to do that. But you may also assign the result of `rezVector[0].first` to an object of type `char*`, such that you get a copy of the referenced value.

So I think that choosing the right type depends on what you want to do with the result. Do you want to change the contents of the pair in place, or do you just want to copy the information?

See the difference in the following example:

```
int main() {
    char val1[] = "Hello";
    char val2[] = "World";
    char val3[] = "out there";

    vector<pair<char*, int> > rezVector; //is  vector I'm using
    rezVector.push_back({val1,10});
    cout << "initial: " << rezVector[0].first << std::endl;

    char*& tempPairFirstReadWrite = rezVector[0].first;
    tempPairFirstReadWrite = val2;
    cout << "changed: " << rezVector[0].first << std::endl;

    char* tempPairFirstReadOnly = rezVector[0].first;
    tempPairFirstReadOnly = val3;
    cout << "not changed again: " << rezVector[0].first << std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
initial: Hello
changed: World
not changed again: World
```

Comment: I had to sort, so I had to change values, not copy. So as I see I was looking for reference to the respective entry